# Slow work of TimeSeriesWindow

Tags: curated-data, date-and-time, time-series

I have financial data (list of time-values pairs). There are more than `13000` elements.

```
data = FinancialData["KO", "OHLCV", {1000, 12, 31}];
```

I need extract from there some part of data which fall into the time interval. These parts are much. I use function `TimeSeriesWindow`, but it`s too slow. For example on this data

```
TimeSeriesWindow[data,{{2013,8,22},{2013,8,26}}];//AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.618035,Null}*)
```

Is the any faster function with the similar functionality? Or how do that operations fater?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not `TimeSeriesWindow` that is making your code slow. What is slowing down your function is the conversion of the data received from `FinancialData` from a `List` to a `TimeSeries` object.
If this conversion is done before `TimeSeriesWindow` is applied, e.g. by

```
tsData=TimeSeries[data]
```

Than

```
TimeSeriesWindow[tsData,{{2013,8,22},{2013,8,26}}]
```

is even faster than the version presented by eldo.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have MMA 10, so I can't reproduce `TimeSeriesWindow`. This is relatively fast:

```
Cases[data, {{y_, m_, d_}, __} /; 
    y >= 2013 && y <= 2013 && m >= 8 && m <= 8 && d >= 22 && d <= 26]; // Timing
```

> {0.031200, Null}

```
DateInterval[data_, {y1_, m1_, d1_}, {y2_, m2_, d2_}] :=
 Cases[data, {{y_, m_, d_}, __} /; 
   y >= y1 && y <= y2 && m >= m1 && m <= m2 && d >= d1 && d <= d2]
```

Comment: That is really faster. Thank you